# do telephone me vs call me

Tags: phrase-meaning

> do telephone me

vs

> call me

What are differencies?

Is verb do is necessary for the sentence gain?

Can I say "Do call me"? At this moment call is not verb, isn`t it?

The first sentence is more outmoded or not? Is it used in practise today?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first version is longer.

Comment: 'Call' is certainly a verb in this context. in 'a telephone call' it is a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Telephone" as a verb is synonymous with (that meaning of) "call". It is probably a bit more formal. (In UK English, "ring" is another possibility).

The use of "Do" there makes the request more insistent, but without making it a peremptory command. It conveys several possible nuances, of which I think the most common are "I would really like you to call me", and "Contrary to what you might be thinking, it is all right for you to call me"